# Integration testing in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm writing a reusable bundle and want to carry out an integration testing of this bundle with the hosting app. The problem is that Symfony doesn't call neither the `DependencyInjection\Extension::load` nor `DependencyInjection\Configuration::getConfigTreeBuilder` method of my bundle, therefore the bundle's service configuration is not loaded and the services are not constructed properly. How can I get Symfony to load everything in tests, as if it was a real request?

Here is my test:

```
namespace Tests\AclAgentBundle;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class IntegrationTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testAgentExistence()
    {
        $container = static::bootKernel()->getContainer();

        $service = $container->get('test.Foo\Bar\Baz');

     //...assertions...
}
```

`test.Foo\Bar\Baz` is an alias of a service, declared in the hosting app's config like

```
services:
    test.Foo\Bar\Baz: '@Foo\Bar\Baz'
```

used to fetch the service via the container's `get` method in tests.

Comment: Did you add your bundle in the Kernel file?

Comment: @tokeeen.com yes I did

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where the problem was. An older cached version of the container was used in the tests, therefore the changes in the configuration of the bundle were not reflected. The command `php bin/console cache:clear --env=test` helped to rebuild the cache. The methods I mentioned in the original question are not supposed to be called when booting the kernel (at least when the cache already exists).

Comment: It’s always better to simply do rm -rf var/cache/*

Comment: @mike why? I heard something about the deprecation of the command but still.